# Cuda 10.1 on Ubuntu version 22.04 installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, tensorflow

After installing the last released Nvidia driver (418.226), I see "Cuda version 10.1" in `nvidia-smi` command (first snapshot). I guess it means I have to install Cuda version 10.1, based on the compatibility table [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#cuda-major-component-versions__table-cuda-toolkit-driver-versions). I use ubuntu 22.04, and my problem is that, as you see in the second snapshot, there is no Cuda toolkit 10.1 released version for 22.04.

Shall I downgrade to ubuntu 18.10 to install Cuda 10.1 compatible with my Nvidia driver (418.226)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is 418 the latest Nvidia driver version you can load for your 765m hardware? The 510 driver supports up to cuda 11.6 on 22.04. You might need to select a Tensorflow version, then a compatible CUDA version, but select a CUDA install which skips the Nvidia driver, which you should set up from the standard Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Yes, the last version I found in Nvidia drivers for 765m was 418. I'm not sure if I find drivers related to other graphic cards, but support 765m? In addition, honestly, I didn't understand your meaning in the second part of your paragraph; from " you might to...". You meant I could install CUDA from standard Ubuntu repos that are not needed to match with the driver? is it works? I thought I should choose them with this support order: graphic driver> Cuda and cuDNN > TensorFlow. Sorry, I asked multiple questions here.

Comment: CUDA and the Nvidia driver version are only linked in the stuff Nvidia supplies, there should be no dependency of CUDA on a particular driver version, so go with what Ubuntu supplies for a driver.  Then, it's up to you to select a compatible CUDA and cuDNN and tensorflow version.

Comment: Your gtx765m has a compute capability of 3.0, so you might be limited to an earlier CUDA release.  My cc of 2.1 on a quadro 1000m is limited to CUDA 8.0 or earlier. Check CUDA 9 and 10 for limitations.

Comment: @ubfan1, as you said, I faced this error: "The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5." But mine is 3. I use Cuda 10.1 and Cudnn 7.6.5. Is there a solution to resolve this error and use GPU for TensorFlow? Shal I buy a brand-new graphic card?

Comment: I did set up on my 2.1 CC Quadro with CUDA 8.0, Cudnn 7.6.5 and tensorflow2.2.0rc2 awhile back.  Didn't do much with it.  If you need Cuda 10.1, you probably need to get a newer card.